# Calculate g^r from g^(xr) and x using Java BigInteger

Tags: java, math, cryptography, biginteger

I am trying to implement a ElGamal-like crypto algorithm using Java's BigInteger objects.

- q is a safe prime in the form 2p+1
- g is a generator of the group 
  [image: Zq]

I want to calculate calculate [image: g^r from g^(xr) and x] but i am having troubles. Using `modInverse` i can calculate [image: 1/x] but if i use this value with `modPow` i only get wrong results.

The only Example i found on the web is [this one](https://encrypted.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=el%20gamal%20modinverse%20biginteger%20c1%20java&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CEwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cs.ucf.edu%2F~dmarino%2Fucf%2Fcis3362%2Fprogs%2FElGamal.java&ei=Uj7vT4DZM4fSsgbf-7iODw&usg=AFQjCNHZHyXteJgdcCIJTFZIAlzDDQiJQQ) where the author uses `modInverse` to calculate [image: 1/x]:

```
        BigInteger temp = c1.modPow(a,p);
        temp = temp.modInverse(p);

        // Print this out.
        System.out.println("Here is c1^ -a = "+temp);
```

I tried some variants (including using modPow with -1) but just cannot get it to work. I think the math should be right but any help is appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
final static BigInteger q = new BigInteger("179769313486231590772930519078902473361797697894230657273430081157732675805500963132708477322407536021120113879871393357658789768814416622492847430639474124377767893424865485276302219601246094119453082952085005768838150682342462881473913110540827237163350510684586298239947245938479716304835356329624225795083");
final static BigInteger p = new BigInteger("89884656743115795386465259539451236680898848947115328636715040578866337902750481566354238661203768010560056939935696678829394884407208311246423715319737062188883946712432742638151109800623047059726541476042502884419075341171231440736956555270413618581675255342293149119973622969239858152417678164812112897541");
final static BigInteger g = new BigInteger("117265744532406309959187881490003058805548219220442880294934902019840205433866971629230940840348591638390822573295684678850519428432938503385192533090834775615734759306193531798190548626342600942782601381215002354918333367595380233608085319759193895027739039963819751637948789055533978566423454988608037601806");

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BigInteger x = new BigInteger("1143167411333064507035595976576260123572705969224418468247407610494944119131645169381885774886951623439260024159767473519706771572117243833759909829897948112642480886709322424314787175230081859236165044801596619590783556439791012887937120324676147585272259948372265307207312838134079528284932292492131276823586631161241002772401238870376093826305673839039010423270418706970005486897400");
    BigInteger r = new BigInteger("28622599320501138892999789676320846139720948572640603818980549097364886339367");

    // g^(xr) = g^(x*r)
    BigInteger g_xr = g.modPow(x.multiply(r), q);

    // 1/x
    BigInteger x_inverse = x.modInverse(q);
    System.out.println(x.multiply(x_inverse).mod(q)); // -> 1 --> correct

    // g^r = g^(xr) ^ (1/x)
    BigInteger g_r = g_xr.modPow(x_inverse, q); // FIXME: wrong result

    System.out.println(g_r); //result
    System.out.println(g.modPow(r, q)); // expected result
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The multiplicative group [image: \mathbb Z^*_q] is of order q−1 — that is to say, g<sup>q−1</sup> = 1 mod q.  Thus, what you need to find is not the inverse of x modulo q, but modulo q−1.

(Also, user1008646 is right that g<sup>xr</sup> = (g<sup>x</sup>)<sup>r</sup> ≠ g<sup>x</sup>g<sup>r</sup> = g<sup>x+r</sup>.)

---

Edit: To summarize the discussion below, the [paper](http://eprint.iacr.org/2009/189.pdf) describing the algorithm the OP is implementing has a typo: instead of working in [image: \mathbb Z^*_q], he needs to work in the order-p subgroup of it.  (Also, the paper is using p and q in the opposite sense to the way the OP is using them here.)

Comment: Thanks, I tried that before but since q is prime, the order of q is q-1 which is not a prime and therefore i cannot find the inverse element.

Comment: If x is not invertible modulo q-1 (i.e. it is even or equal to p), then there exists no y such that g^(xry) = g^r for all r.  If you need one, then either your algorithm is wrong or you've made some mistake in implementing it. Seeing an original description of the algorithm would help in telling which is the case.

Comment: By the way, in standard [ElGamal encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ElGamal_encryption), you'd instead calculate g^r = g^(xr) / g^x = g^(xr) g^(-x).  You don't need to calculate _any_ modular inverses for that; just `g_r = g_xr.multiply( g.modPow(-x,p) ).mod(p)` is enough.

Comment: Thanks again. The algorithm is from [this paper](eprint.iacr.org/2009/189.pdf) - the relevant part is this (p11): "Choose two primes p and q such that q|p−1 and the bit-length of q is the security parameter κ. Let g be a generator of group G, which is a subgroup of Z*q with order q." You're right - the group is specified to have a prime order which would make it possible to find an inverse element. But is it even possible to find a subgroup of Z*q that has the order q?

Comment: No, that has to be a typo.  What they mean is "subgroup of Z_p^* with order q".  (Ps. For p = 2q+1, an easy way to find a generator of the order-q subgroup G is to pick a random number r modulo p, square it and check that the result isn't 1. If it isn't, g = r^2 is a generator of G.)

Comment: Thanks for the hint and all your time!

Comment: No problem.  Ps. Since the issue seems to be more about crypto / math than about programming, you may get better help with it at the [Cryptography Stack Exchange](http://crypto.stackexchange.com). If you like, you can flag your question for mod attention and ask for it to be migrated there.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with BigInteger, but I believe `g^x * g^r = g^(x+r)`.
It looks like you're basing your code on `g^x * g^r = g^(x*r)`.
Does that help?

Comment: thanks, I corrected that but i'm still getting wrong results.